# Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} x\sin(\frac1x); & x \neq 1 \\ 1, & x = 1 \\ \end{cases}$ and $A =\{ x \in R : f(x) = 1\}.$ Prove that $A$ has two elements.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let 
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x \neq 1 \\ 
> 1, & x = 1 
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   and $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) = 1\}$ then prove that $A$ has two elements.

**My approach :**

Can we use : $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

which implies $A$ has only one point which is $1.$

Please suggest which is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

$|sin \, t |<|t|$ for all $t \neq 0$. Hence we cannot have $x \sin (\frac 1 x) =1$ with $x \neq 0$. [ take $t =\frac 1 x$].